# how to set xml namespace value in Javacode Android

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

i am developing an app where i have to create an xml item in my activity dynamically like circle image view. shown below.

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/p_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

now in my java code i am creating a new instance of it and i want to change the

```
app:border_width="2dp"
app:border_color="@android:color/white"
```

how to do that?

```
 CircleImageView imageView = new CircleImageView(mContext);
 imageView.border_width="2dp";      //these lines are giving error.
 imageView.border_color="@android:color/white"; //these lines are giving error.
 imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
 imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

any help will be appriciated thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should have their own getter/setters, you can use them to set values:

```
imageView.setBorderColor(android.graphics.Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // Or Color.WHITE for white
imageView.setBorderWidth(2);
```

You can have a look at how fields are encapsulated at the source code: [CircleImageView.java](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView/blob/master/circleimageview/src/main/java/de/hdodenhof/circleimageview/CircleImageView.java)